# How to select edge randomly from graph in R?

Tags: r, random, igraph, edge-list

I have a regular graph and wanna delete randomly edge from graph. How to select edges randomly till I can delete?

```
library(igraph)
g = sample_k_regular(10,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sample(x,n)` function in base R along with `delete_edges` from `igraph`.

For example, if you want to delete 5 edges:

```
library(igraph)
g = sample_k_regular(10,3)
g1 <- delete_edges(g,sample(E(g),5))
```

`E(g)` gets a list of edges that sample randomly samples from.